# how to scroll complete screen by recyclerView while there's another recyclerView along with that

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I've two RecyclerView in a single screen. First one is scrolling horizontal. second one is vertical. When I scroll vertical RecyclerView, It scrolls by its edges only, not as parent in whole screen. attached image describe question better.

[Screenshot Vertical RecyclerView, To understand Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pofM4.png)

My requirement is when i scroll RecyclerView. It scroll the whole screen

Here's Code of RecyclerView in MainActicity

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ShopActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/home_app_bar" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/titleShopContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
            android:padding="@dimen/paddingToScreenEdge">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shopTitle"
                style="@style/title_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/shop" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_view_all"
                style="@style/link_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/shopTitle"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="@string/view_all" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_Shop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/titleShopContainer"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shopRequirementTitle"
            style="@style/title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/rv_Shop"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/paddingToScreenEdge"
            android:text="Requirement" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_shop_Requirement"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/shopRequirementTitle"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/paddingToScreenEdge" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            style="@style/floating_action_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_plus"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:rippleColor="@color/colorGreyLight" />
    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here's CustomAdapter(RecyclerView.Adapter)

```
public class CustomAdapterShopRequirement extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    ArrayList shopImages, shopRatings, shopAddress, shopPosition, shopName;
    Context context;

    public CustomAdapterShopRequirement(Context context, ArrayList shopName, ArrayList shopImages, ArrayList shopRatings, ArrayList shopAddress, ArrayList shopPosition) {
        this.context = context;
        this.shopName = shopName;
        this.shopImages = shopImages;
        this.shopRatings = shopRatings;
        this.shopAddress = shopAddress;
        this.shopPosition = shopPosition;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ShopRequirementViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_shop_requirement_row, parent, false);
        ShopRequirementViewHolder viewHolder = new ShopRequirementViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        ((ShopRequirementViewHolder) holder).imageView.setImageResource((Integer) shopImages.get(position));
        ((ShopRequirementViewHolder) holder).name.setText((CharSequence) shopName.get(position));
        ((ShopRequirementViewHolder) holder).rating.setText((CharSequence) shopRatings.get(position));
        ((ShopRequirementViewHolder) holder).address.setText((CharSequence) shopAddress.get(position));
        ((ShopRequirementViewHolder) holder).position.setText((CharSequence) shopPosition.get(position));

        ((ShopRequirementViewHolder) holder).itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, shopName.get(position) + "  selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return shopName.size();
    }
}

class ShopRequirementViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView name, rating, address, position;

    public ShopRequirementViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shop_requirement_image);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_shop_requirement_name);
        rating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_shop_requirement_rating);
        address = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_shop_requirement_address);
        position = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_shop_requirement_position);
    }
}
```

And finally here's MainActivity class file

public class ShopActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
RecyclerView rvShopRequirement;


ArrayList shopImage = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(R.mipmap.shop1, R.mipmap.shop2, R.mipmap.banner2, R.mipmap.banner3, R.mipmap.banner4));
ArrayList shopName = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Nagori Hashmati", "Nagori Lucky Dairy", "Simnani Tea Point", "Sufi darbar tea and milk center", "Nagori Dairy"));
ArrayList shopAddress = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Near MK road, Kurla", "Behind Dharave Bus stop Dharave(E)", "Bandra Terminus (W)", "Santacruz", "govandi"));
ArrayList shopRating = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("3.5", "4", "4.8", "5", "4.5"));
ArrayList shopPosition = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Galla", "Table", "Stamp", "Galla", "Tea Supply"));

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop);


    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    toolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.toolbar_logo);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_shop);

    rvShop = findViewById(R.id.rv_Shop);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    rvShop.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    CustomAdapterShop customAdapterShop = new CustomAdapterShop(ShopActivity.this, shopImages, shopNames, shopDistrict);
    rvShop.setAdapter(customAdapterShop);

    rvShopRequirement = findViewById(R.id.rv_shop_Requirement);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager1=new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    rvShopRequirement.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager1);
    CustomAdapterShopRequirement customAdapterShopRequirement=new CustomAdapterShopRequirement(ShopActivity.this,shopName,shopImage,shopRating,shopAddress,shopPosition);
    rvShopRequirement.setAdapter(customAdapterShopRequirement);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_account:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AccountActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_shop:
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_person:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PersonActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_social:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SocialActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.settings:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.faq:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FAQ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.subscription:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Subscription", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.sort:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sort", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.filter:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Filter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: You should add only one recycleView and in that at first position you should add another recycleView which will scroll horizontally as you want. And after that position show your vertical data

Comment: @BhavenShah Sir, can you please elaborate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just have to wrap your code between app_bar and bottom_navigation into NestedScrollView like this:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
            android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/otherInfoLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">

                //your code here

            </LinearLayout

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you sir to show your interest, I found same answer somewhere else. I'll upvote you.